# How to update an oracle table joined with two tables with values from a fourth table?

Tags: database, oracle, join, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a main table (T1) which's to be joined with two tables (T2 and T3) and need a way to update one column from T1 with values from another table. I can't seem to find an update statement which does the update operation accurately.

```
SELECT
    T1.VALUE --This value to be updated as New_value from New_table
FROM
    TABLE1 T1,  TABLE2 T2,  TABLE3 T3
WHERE
    T1.VALUE = 'Out_dated value'   --This value to be updated from New_table
AND T1.VA_ID=T2.VA_ID
AND T1.SI_ID=T3.SI_ID;
```

[image: New table]

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want to do. What is "New_table"?

Comment: @SuperPoney, New_table is the one which contains the values which are supposed to be in the main table T1.
The new_table has two columns having the old incorrect values and new corrected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you listed some sample data and expected results. But I think you want something like this:

```
update table1 t1
set t1.value = (select new_value from new_table where old_value = t1.value)
where exists (SELECT 1
    FROM
    TABLE2 T2,  TABLE3 T3
    WHERE T1.VA_ID=T2.VA_ID
    AND T1.SI_ID=T3.SI_ID)
```

You didn't show the column names for `NEW_TABLE`, I'm assuming here that they're `NEW_VALUE` and `OLD_VALUE`.

Comment: I've been careless; the tables' aliases are incorrectly mentioned. I've just changed them.

Comment: I thought that was odd. Well, it doesn't change my answer much.